# Restart terminal application with a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need a .bat file that will close and re-open start.cmd (C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\PocketMine-MP\start.cmd) <-- that's the file location. I need it to close and re-open every 75 min. The terminal has to close it can't stay open and launch another all I've gotten so far is:

```
@echo off
:loop
start "start.cmd" "C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\PocketMine-MP\start.cmd 
timeout /t 20
taskkill /f /im "start.cmd" >nul
goto loop
```

Its starting the terminal every 20 seconds like I want it too but its not closing the old one.
If anyone can help it would assist me and my small network greatly.

Comment: 1. It's a bad idea to name a batch file the same as a built-in command like `start`. 2. `/im` image name is `cmd.exe` not `start.cmd`. That's the window title, so you probably want `/fi "windowtitle eq start.cmd"`.

Comment: That worked to open the terminal program but it still isn't closing it and re-starting the process, it just starts it and then waits 20s and starts it again.

Answer (score 2):

Rename `start.cmd` to `bat_start.cmd` then try the following.

```
@echo off
:loop
start "bat_start.cmd" "C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\PocketMine-MP\bat_start.cmd"
timeout /t 20
taskkill /f /fi "windowtitle eq bat_start.cmd*" /im "cmd.exe" >nul
goto loop
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use same file for control the loop and start file again, then it's fall in recursion. Following example work for me,

```
@echo off
:loop
start "test2" "C:\test2.bat"
timeout /t 60
taskkill /f /fi "windowtitle eq test2*" /im "cmd.exe" >nul
goto loop
```

test2 file

```
@echo off    
echo "start job here"    
:: Do your work here     
pause  :: remove the pause, it's just for simulating 
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TimeCommander plugin. Set to run a restart command every 75 minutes.